# Проблемы при работе Android Studio в режиме offline

Tags: android, android-studio, offline

При попытке собрать release версию проекта в режиме offline или просто без интернета появляется ошибка

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.3).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar
```

Плюс список недостающих файлов среди которых есть например `lint-26.6.3.jar, lint-checks-26.6.3.jar`.

Что пробовал сделать.

Начала искать похожие файлы (кроме lint-gradle), чтобы добавить их вручную. Нашел в папке SDK версии 20.0.0-dev, пробовал копировать туда.
Потом нашел в папке установки Gradle несколько версий 25.0.0 и т.д. но там путь со строковым "хешем".
Решил добавить "локальный репозитарий".

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
         maven { url "d:\test\" }
         //или так
         flatDir( "d:\test\" )
         ...
    }
}
```

Не работает.

Вопрос: можно ли заставить Android Studio использовать старые версии библиотек или как добавить новые.

---

Дополнение.

Создал папку в `%UserName% \.m2\repository\`
Добавил `mavenLocal()`
пробовал скопировать первый файл (см. код ошибки) в корень, потом в

```
com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar
com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar
com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle.jar
```

не работает.

Comment: Отключить оффлайн режим, подключиться к интернету и собрать один раз. В дальнейшем должно работать без сети до тех пор пока вы не измените версии инструментария сборки. Другой вариант: скачать нужную версию из google maven репозитория (ссылка указана в ошибке) и забросить в локальный. Чтобы использовать старые версии нужно откатить инструментарий до соответствующих версий и это гораздо больше гемора - их тоже может не найтись в кеше грэдла плюс в коде вылезут проблемы

Comment: @woesss нет возможности подключиться к инету (иначе этот вопрос бы не задавал). Есть возможность загрузить файлы на стороне и скопировать.

Comment: Значит второй вариант. Выкачивайте всё по ссылкам и кидайте в локальный репозиторий. В гредл вписать `mavenLocal()`, файлы разложить в `<UserHome>/.m2/repository/`, ну или как у вас прописать путь к репоситорию, если хотите его сделать в другом месте. Путь к файлу относительно репозитория должен быть таким же как в ссылке после `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/`

Comment: Копируйте артефакты в локальный мавен-репозиторий. Он находится в `.m2/repository` в домашней директории (в windows обычно домашняя директория это C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\). Чтобы теперь подключить локальный репозиторий, напишите `mavenLocal()` в списке репозиториев.

Comment: @woesss я дополнил вопрос

Comment: Похоже гугл заменил ftp-подобную веб-версию репозитория на какую-то хрень. Я не знаю как бы теперь попроще это сделать, но нужны все файлы из той же папки. Можно попытаться ручками: на каждый jar скачать pom (заменив расширение в адресе). Потом и к jar и к pom добавить `.sha1` и их тоже загрузить. Закинуть всё это добро в локальный репозиторий.

Comment: *гугл заменил ftp-подобную веб-версию репозитория на какую-то хрень* @woesss это боль (((

Comment: @Style-7 добавьте `mavenLocal()` не только в репозитории проекта, но и в репозитории [`buildscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923766). Скорей всего Lint используется не самим приложением, а это плагин для билд-скрипта. Репозитории для билд-скрипта прописываются в `buildscript {}` секции, либо в `pluginManagement {}`. Кроме jar вам нужно будет скопировать и другие файлы (как об этом написал выше woesss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопируйте артефакты в локальный мавен-репозиторий, который находится в `.m2/repository` в вашей домашней директории.

И добавьте локальный репозиторий в проект:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        ...
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        ...
    }
}
```

Тогда если какой-то артефакт будет найден в локальном репозитории, то будет использваться он (должны совпасть group, name и version артефакта).

Кроме jar еще нужно будет скопировать все файлы с метаданными.

Все файлы должны находиться в директории:

```
.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3
```

Список файлов:

[lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar)
[lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar.sha1](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle-26.6.3.jar.sha1)
[lint-gradle-26.6.3.pom](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle-26.6.3.pom)
[lint-gradle-26.6.3.pom.sha1](https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.6.3/lint-gradle-26.6.3.pom.sha1)

Comment: Спасибо, я дополнил вопрос

Comment: меня интересует как правильно составить путь к файлу если в коде ошибки я вижу путь "Could not find lint-gradle.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.3)" , я имею ввиду нужно ли оставлять номер версии в файле, какие нужны подпапки и т.д.

Comment: Обновил ответ, не забудьте добавить `mavenLocal()` как в `allprojects`, так и в `buildscript` (в новых проектах pluginManagement вместо buildscript). Вам нужно скопировать по крайней мере 4 файла: `jar`, `jar.sha1`, `pom`, `pom.sha1`.

Comment: Почти получилось. Застрял на последнем файле "com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.2.0" путь "https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/error_prone_annotations-2.2.0.jar". И еще вопрос, а можно ли подключить maven, он доступен для меня но там нет некоторых файлов (например первого), но все равно легче чем вручную "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.2.0/"

Comment: Получилось у меня. Локальный репозитарий не работал для файлов в jcenter, но прекрасно работал для google. Я добавил mavenCentral и он работает для файлов jcenter, но не работает для google. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не очень понятно. Но jcenter по-хорошему не стоит уже использовать, он устарел. Если есть возможность его убрать -- убирайте.

Comment: Дело в том, что если я его убираю вылетает ошибка. Еще вопрос, прочему не происходит установка/кеширование, постоянно идет этот запрос на файлы.

Comment: Разобрался с maven - версий этих файлов там нет, так что все правильно. А есть ли зеркало репозитария google? И не понял можно ли AS заставить работать с Lint версии ниже скажем 25, откуда берется 26,6,3?

Comment: Откуда берется 26.6.3 можно посмотреть в дереве зависимостей, выполнив команду `./gradlew app:dependencies` (либо `./gradlew buildEnvironment`). Линт тянется из зависимости com.android.tools.build:gradle. Если вручную выставить другую версию, то, возможно, наткнетесь на новые ошибки. Создавайте новые вопросы, если с чем-то еще не разобрались.

Comment: Спасибо........